# Symfony doesn't take me the handler of an API

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, sylius

I am doing an API in a framework called Sylius that uses the symfony framework as a base.
I am currently not recognized by the API controller class that solves the API logic

I have a controller with its respective declaration:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Controller\Order;

use EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Factory\ValidationErrorViewFactoryInterface;
use EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Request\Order\CustomerOrderCancellationRequest;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

final class CustomerOrderCancellationAction
{
    /** @var ViewHandlerInterface */
    private $viewHandler;

    /** @var MessageBusInterface */
    private $bus;

    /** @var ValidatorInterface */
    private $validator;

    /** @var ValidationErrorViewFactoryInterface */
    private $validationErrorViewFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ViewHandlerInterface $viewHandler,
        MessageBusInterface $bus,
        ValidatorInterface $validator,
        ValidationErrorViewFactoryInterface $validationErrorViewFactory
    ) {
        $this->viewHandler = $viewHandler;
        $this->bus = $bus;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->validationErrorViewFactory = $validationErrorViewFactory;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        $pickupRequest = new CustomerOrderCancellationRequest($request);
        $validationResults = $this->validator->validate($pickupRequest);

        if (0 === count($validationResults)) {
            $this->bus->dispatch($pickupRequest->getCommand());

            return $this->viewHandler->handle(View::create(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT));
        }

        return $this->viewHandler->handle(View::create($this->validationErrorViewFactory->create($validationResults), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
    }
}
```

The controller declared it as follows:

```
<service id="sylius.shop_api_plugin.controller.order.customer_order_cancellation_action"
                 class="EasyCommerce\ShopApiPlugin\Controller\Order\CustomerOrderCancellationAction"
        >
            <argument type="service" id="fos_rest.view_handler" />
            <argument type="service" id="sylius_shop_api_plugin.command_bus" />
            <argument type="service" id="validator" />
            <argument type="service" id="sylius.shop_api_plugin.factory.validation_error_view_factory" />
 </service>
```

I declare the route in the following way:

```
sylius_shop_api_customer_order_cancellation:
    path: /orders/{tokenValue}/cancellation
    methods: [PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.shop_api_plugin.controller.order.customer_order_cancellation_action
```

And it returns the following error:

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Attempted to load class \"CustomerOrderCancellationAction\" from namespace \"EasyCommerce\\ShopApiPlugin\\Controller\\Order\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace?"
}
```

***To test if the route was well configured I pointed it to another controller and it works. The problem is with the controller you create.***

Comment: Where is that code located within the project and how do you autoload its classes?

Comment: I could solve it with a composer dump-autoload. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there were two different namespaces in the main project I had to clear cache:

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

And then reload the composer:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

That way it reloads all the namespaces